# Rails Geocoder gem & Google Autocomplete API - Query Limit Reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, heroku, rails-geocoder

I have tried to implement Google's autocomplete API, when user types a location and presses to enter, A map with markers load in another page. It looks exactly like Airbnb. Search, then map..

My problem is, lately I am getting an error of "query size limit reached". I have read all the posts about this issue here but could not find a solution.

Basically, when user types an address as string, I get that string and use it for google maps' init lat & long. I use geocoder gem and server as Heroku.

Here is how it looks like;

```
@search = params[:search]
if !@search.nil? && @search.strip != ""  
    location =  Geocoder.search(params[:search])
    @initlat = location[0].latitude
    @initlng = location[0].longitude 
end
```

Why I am getting this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

```
Users of the standard API:

2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
```

**Paid use**

```
Enable pay-as-you-go billing to unlock higher quotas:

$0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily.

ENABLE BILLING
```

just click on **ENABLE BILLING** button and get API key and set geocoder.rb

```
# config/initializers/geocoder.rb
Geocoder.configure(

  # geocoding service (see below for supported options):
  :lookup => :yandex,

  # IP address geocoding service (see below for supported options):
  :ip_lookup => :maxmind,

  # to use an API key:
  :api_key => "...",

  # geocoding service request timeout, in seconds (default 3):
  :timeout => 5,

  # set default units to kilometers:
  :units => :km,

  # caching (see below for details):
  :cache => Redis.new,
  :cache_prefix => "..."

)
```

Comment: Instead of using Geocoder.search(params[:search]), is it better to send lat lng values to controller when place_changed in autocomplete?